# How to send data from flash player into an external executable through a pipe

Tags: actionscript-3, pipe, flash

I want to send data generated by a flash module into an external executable in windows. From what I've learnt about interprocess communication, I think it is appropriate to use pipes in this case. I am using Flash professional CS5 and when a 'trace' command is used in actionscript the ouput will be displayed in the output window in flash professional. I think Flash pipes the data into the output window and if so is it possible to obtain the handle to that pipe. Is there a way by which I can write the output from flash player itself when the trace commands are executed or the data generated on an event directly into the buffer of a pipe.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tricks using a Flash Badge, AIR app. and C# console app..
We can send params to an AIR app. from BADGE and receive it using:

```
protected function onInit(event:FlexEvent):void{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE, onBrowserInvoke);}
protected function onBrowserInvoke(e:BrowserInvokeEvent):void{
    //reading args
    var a:String = e.arguments[0];
    //Now we can run *.exe from windows using:
    if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
    {
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("ExecutableApp.exe");
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments.push(a);
        var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        //dispatched when the process will be finished
        process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT,onProcessDone);
        //run
        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    }
    else Alert.show("Native process are not supported\nPrinter settings may be wrong!");
}
```

It's a long way, but certainly works! At least for me it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the code Alex. I actually am a newbie to Actionscript programming and some explanation of the code from you would be really helpful. The output commands in my flash module are generated when I click a button. Also mine is a standalone module so I don't BrowserInvokeEvent can be generated in my case. Also when you used "ExecutableApp.exe", did you mean that is the name of the application that will be opened by Flash.

Comment: If so where should the .exe file be placed and does this run only for AIR applications. Also in the beginning the code starts working when a FlexEvent is generated.  How can I modify this to my needs. Thanks

Comment: 1) Create AIR Badge - [Tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/badge_for_air.html)
It can be a simple button on the web page or a big application that comunicate with server.
When you click on the button AIR app will run and BrowserInvokeEvent will be dispatched inside the AIR app.
After that you are free to run .exe application using code above.
2) Create AIR app. - [Tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html)
Flash - > AIR - > EXE (*.exe can be placed wherever you want)